# Most effecient way to retrive and save data to mongodb via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Lets say we have a collection of user documnets in the mongodb database and each document contains huge amount of fields and data.

We may want to save the email of the user to its document right? So first we need to return the documnet of the user and then save the email :

`const account = db.Account.findOne({email}); account.email = value; account.save;`

As I said the document has a lot of extra fields we don't want to modify we only want to select and modify the email feild, Now I wonder :

1. if this has any impact on performance and the duration of the request?

2)Do I need to only select the email field for purpose of enhancing the performance?

3. What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: Good question. Not sure myself but 1 potential approach could be to separate large fields into different collection. Then, if you were to update only small fields (like email), the performance would be great.

Comment: If you are modifying only a single field, why not use update?